# Is there seconds_in_month just like days_in_month?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following code that divides the dataframe by the number of days in a month.

`df.apply(lambda col: col / df.index.days_in_month)`

I was wondering if there was a similar function to divide by the number of seconds in a month?
I tried `df.apply(lambda col: col / df.index.seconds_in_month)` but I get an attribute error

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'seconds_in_month'

Can anyone help me with this?

Solution:
`days_in_month * 86400` did the trick

Comment: `days_in_month * 86400`?

Comment: Since "seconds in a day" is a constant, no function is needed.